# Popup window using input text and onclick button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for the solution :
opening the Popup window by inserting a value for example.

if your site is: **www.example.com/**
by inserting a value as a text let's take ' results ' and clicking on the button show us this Popup page:
**www.example.com/results**

actually I'm using this Code,  but that shows the result in the same page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
 <title>Redirect url in Javascript</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<input id = "url" type = "text" name = "url"
      placeholder = "Enter a url here"> 
<input type = "submit" name = "button" onclick = "fun()"> 
<script> 
function fun() { 
 var url= document.getElementById("url").value; 
 document.write("Redirecting to the url in 3 seconds..."); 
 setTimeout(function(){window.location = url;}, 3000); 
} 




</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You want to redirect to www.example.com/results on button click.

Comment: What kind of pop-up window are you particularly looking for? Is the browser supposed to (a) open a new tab? Or (b) a true modal(?) pop-up window? Or (c) a HTML overlay that's supposed to look like a pop-up window?

Comment: I'm want to open the url as a overly or pop-up window

Comment: Yes after input results and clicking on the button to redirect to  www.example.com/results but it should open in pop-up, not in the same window  cse_vikashgupta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to window.open(url) with an extra parameter like below.

```
function fun() { 
    var url= document.getElementById("url").value; 
    document.write("Redirecting to the url in 3 seconds..."); 
    var currentUrl = window.location.url;
    setTimeout(function(){    window.open(currentUrl+"/"+url, '_blank', 'location=yes,height=500,width=1000,scrollbars=yes,status=yes')}, 3000); 
}
```

Third Param describe how your new window would look like.(For ex. it's height and width)
For more info [Read Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Search for Window features in Article.

Answer (score 0):

you should use 
`window.open(url)`
and you can use `` or "" with + to create the url that you want

Comment: I tried it but that doesn't show the pop-up in a new window

Comment: although it worked for me but if you add _blank as a second parameter it will open in a new tab

Comment: setTimeout(function(){window.open("https://" + url,"_blank");}, 3000);     }

Answer (score 0):

two issues with your code:

1) you need to include https:// in the url
2) on js fiddle and stackoverflow you can only test their domain

so if you enter www.stackoverflow.com you'll see that the code below works as intended

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
 <title>Redirect url in Javascript</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<input id = "url" type = "text" name = "url"
      placeholder = "Enter a url here"> 
<input type = "submit" name = "button" onclick = "fun()"> 
<script> 
function fun() { 
 var url= document.getElementById("url").value; 
 document.write("Redirecting to the url in 3 seconds..."); 
 setTimeout(function(){window.location = "https://" + url;}, 3000); 
} 




</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```